# Adding a handwritten font for logo

Tags: logo, text, font-recommendation

I have been using sans-serif font for the following logo which I am designing for a family baking business:

[image]

I now want to switch to a handwritten font, and need some ideas of how to implement it.

[image]

Can somebody please recommend a handwritten font that would be best suited to this image? The sans-serif fonts seem better fitted for the task, but I would prefer a handwritten font. Can someone please provide recommendations of fonts to use and maybe image placement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already stated, your logo is constructed with homogenous strokes so your font should ideally follow that. I would personally design the type myself.

Something you can do if you're not comfortable creating the type yourself from scratch is to base it on a typeface that you like the shapes of... this for example is a quick recreation of the example script typeface you showed us:

[image]

Which when given a similar stroke to the rest of the logo (and a little modification, I literally spent 2 minutes on this though), looks like this:

[image]

Comment: We tend to perceive type strokes as heavier than strokes in graphic elements, so I think I'd give the text perhaps 80% of the stroke width. Visually, it appears a bit too heavy compared to the drawings here. Still +1.

Comment: @Janus sure, absolutely, they should be *perceivably* the same width, which often means not *actually* being the same width (not just with type)

Answer (score 1):

Your logo obviously uses constructed shapes and homogeneous stroke (monoline). A typical handwritten typeface such as the one in your example will not follow either paradigm, which causes dissonance. Probably the best choice of typeface would be a geometric monoline sans.

If it really has to be something handwritten (and the logo should stay the same), you have to live with handwritten typefaces not being constructed by nature, but you can at least obtain a constant stroke (matching your logo). This should narrow down your choices of fonts considerably.

Searching for the keywords *monoline* and *script* should yield a list of suitable fonts, e.g., [this search](http://www.myfonts.com/search/monoline+script/).

Comment: Thanks, if possible - can you recommend any fonts with a similar stroke?